# TYPO3 TCA own evaluation (validation) for a combination of three fields

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I read the [documentation on the eval property for type=input](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Input/Properties/Eval.html#custom-eval-rules) and tried my own evaluations.

It should evaluate a combination of three fields with this logic:
start_date AND end_date required (not empty) OR date_on_request required.

Class is loaded and function evaluateFieldValue() works, but I miss the feedback in form.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Evaluation;

class StartDateAndEndDateOrDateOnRequestEvaluation {

    /**
     * JavaScript code for client side validation/evaluation
     *
     * @return string JavaScript code for client side validation/evaluation
     */
    public function returnFieldJS() {
        return 'return value;';
    }

    /**
     * Server-side validation/evaluation on saving the record
     *
     * @param string $value The field value to be evaluated
     * @param string $is_in The "is_in" value of the field configuration from TCA
     * @param bool $set Boolean defining if the value is written to the database or not.
     * @return string Evaluated field value
     */
    public function evaluateFieldValue($value, $is_in, &$set) {

        foreach($_POST['data']['tx_extension_domain_model_course'] as $id => $course) {
            if ( (!empty($course['start_date']) && !empty($course['start_date'])) || !empty($course['date_on_request']) ) {
                $set = true;
            } else {
                $set = false;
            }
        }
        return $value;
    }

    /**
     * Server-side validation/evaluation on opening the record
     *
     * @param array $parameters Array with key 'value' containing the field value from the database
     * @return string Evaluated field value
     */
    public function deevaluateFieldValue(array $parameters) {
        return $parameters['value'];
    }

}
```

Im looking for examples, how I can do validation in JavaScript (returnFieldJS):

- How I get the three fields?
- How can set error classes?

And what should I check in evaluateFieldValue()?

Answer (score 0):

The methods `returnFieldJS()` and `deevaluateFieldValue(array $parameters)` are not called for `datetime` fields. That is why I guess there is no clean way to add JavaScript validation to `datetime` fields. 
To get an error message in the backend you can however use the `FlashMessageService`. I implemented an example to check that the `course_end` date is after the `course_start` date:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Evaluation;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessage;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessageService;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager;

class StartDateAndEndDateOrDateOnRequestEvaluation {
    /**
     * JavaScript code for client side validation/evaluation
     *
     * @return string JavaScript code for client side validation/evaluation
     */
    public function returnFieldJS() 
    {
        return 'return value;';
    }

    /**
     * Server-side validation/evaluation on saving the record
     *
     * @param string $value The field value to be evaluated
     * @param string $is_in The "is_in" value of the field configuration from TCA
     * @param bool $set Boolean defining if the value is written to the database or not.
     * @return string Evaluated field value
     */
    public function evaluateFieldValue($value, $is_in, &$set)
    {
        $formData = GeneralUtility::_GP('data');
        $courseId = key($formData['tx_extension_domain_model_course']);
        $course = $formData['tx_extension_domain_model_course'][$courseId];

        $courseStart = new \DateTime($course['course_start']);
        $courseEnd = new \DateTime($course['course_end']);

        if ($courseStart > $courseEnd) {
            $this->flashMessage('Invalid field value', 'Course end date can not be before course start date!', FlashMessage::ERROR);
            $set = false; //do not save value
        }

        return $value;
    }

    /**
     * Server-side validation/evaluation on opening the record
     *
     * @param array $parameters Array with key 'value' containing the field value from the database
     * @return string Evaluated field value
     */
    public function deevaluateFieldValue(array $parameters) 
    {
        return $parameters['value'];
    }

    /**
     * @param string $messageTitle
     * @param string $messageText
     * @param int $severity
     */
    protected function flashMessage($messageTitle, $messageText, $severity = FlashMessage::ERROR)
    {
        $message = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(
            FlashMessage::class,
            $messageText,
            $messageTitle,
            $severity,
            true
        );

        $objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
        $flashMessageService = $objectManager->get(FlashMessageService::class);
        $messageQueue = $flashMessageService->getMessageQueueByIdentifier();
        $messageQueue->addMessage($message);
    }
}
```